# NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Tags: pandas, import, nameerror

I am attempting run in Jupyter

```
import pandas as pd                     
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          # plotting
import numpy as np                       # dense matrices
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix      # sparse matrices
%matplotlib inline
```

However when loading the dataset with

```
wiki = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')
# add id column
wiki['id'] = range(0, len(wiki))
wiki.head(10)
```

### the following error persists

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-56330c326580> in <module>()
----> 1 wiki = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')
      2 # add id column
      3 wiki['id'] = range(0, len(wiki))
      4 wiki.head(10)

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: most probably you'll need to reevaluate your cells from the first one and down to the failing one. also make sure they're of same python version type if you have multiple

Comment: I am a new Python learner and using Jupyter Notebook. For me cell reevaluation worked.

Answer (score 23):

Select `Restart & Clear Output` and run the cells again from the beginning.

I had the same issue, and as [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235433/ivan) suggested in the comment, this resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

If you came here from a duplicate, notice also that your code needs to contain

```
import pandas as pd
```

in the first place. If you are using a notebook like Jupyter and it's already there, or if you just added it, you probably need to re-evaluate the cell, as suggested in the currently top-voted answer by martin-martin.

Answer (score 0):

python version will need 3.6 above, I think you have been use the python 2.7. Please select from top right for your python env version.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to load / import Pandas first

Comment: This would be better as a comment (when you can do that) and welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

When stepping through the Anaconda Navigator demo, I found that pressing "play" on the first line before inputting the second line resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces this issue and pandas is clearly imported like in the case above. You will encounter this error because the import cell is not being executed.

Make sure to toggle it to code and execute that block again
[image]