# Load a Module in Notebook

Tags: python

I am working in google collab and have loaded a module to the existing note book with the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/')
import Input_API as repo
```

when I call a function within repo, using

```
portfolio=repo.input_apc(file_name_in)
```

I get the error:

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Input_API.py in input_apc(file_name)

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

In def input_apc I am trying to load a csv file using pandas. At the top of Input_API.py I have the indication

```
import pandas as pd
```

The error happens when calling the function from a notebook and the function itself is in a separate module.

I cannot understand the error, or why pd is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'pd' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407090/nameerror-name-pd-is-not-defined)

Comment: No, I have tried that and it does not work. Also, the link you mention is for an error within the notebook. I get the error when loading data using a module. Thanks anyway.