Jupyterlab panel preview pd not defined when on line to import pandas as pd
I am trying to see Panel preview of Jupyterlab project and I am getting the error
"import pandas as pd\n",
     ^^
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

I have already tried restarting the notebook and clearing all output,everything works fine in the normal jupyterlab.
this is my imports block,there is no indentation at all
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

Edit: For anyone else who has this issue, It went away when i removed the %matplotlib inline

Try %pip install pandas in the notebook. Are you sure you get this exact error?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40407090/2232127 check if any of the answers provide a solution

If not, make sure to provide a [mre], your current code shouldn't give you this error.
